# Need to set table as world origin with ARCore/ARKit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I'm developing a table top game where I want the digital world to adapt to the table (play area) the user is pointing at, if this makes sense. I want to detect the table, its estimated size and lock the content to the surface. If I have a grass field that I want to have on my table, that grass field would adapt to different sizes of tables. See video below, if the table would have been narrower, the gameobjects would move closer to eachother in order to fit the content on to the surface.

Here's a example on what i'm looking for: https://youtu.be/S14AVwaBF-Y?t=48s

Comment: Your question is broad given that the ARCore for Unity has a sample app: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample You should update your question with more info as to what you've tried.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I understand, i've updated the question for you to hopefully understand the idea behind it.

Comment: BTW, ARKit has Image Recognition as part of the recent ARKit 1.5 (iOS 11.3) update. You would use that to get the pose of the marker, and since you know where it is, you'd place your game relative to the marker's center location. ARCore doesn't yet have this capability out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should use an AR technology like ARCore or ARkit (like you already included in your title). With that you would scan the environment and it will give you tracked planes (like the table).

From that you can get the its size, and then procedurally generate you virtual ground (like the grass), and also procedurally place your other virtual objects based on the size of the ground.

This is a very broad subject to cover since the approach you take greatly depends on your specific requirements, but maybe you could take a look at procedural generation, and from there write your own algorithm to fit your needs.

If your ground is just a plane, then you could either create a polygon mesh to match the tracked plane, or just modify the tracked plane and add materials, colliders etc. For this look into how meshes work and how they are created here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html

For the objects placement, you need to find algorithms on how to procedurally place objects (like buildings) in the available space.

Comment: Interesting. So let's say that we already have a specific table that is going to be used for the tracking, so we can skip the procedurally generated part, and place the scene as it's build in unity on top of the surface. Could one use markers to easier map out the table and orient the play area created in Unity. If so how would one go about to create something like this. Because basically all we want is the user to see the diamond tracking pattern on the table, to see that the table is mapped out, and press a button to place out the grassfield for example on top of a table.

Comment: If the table to be used is always the same one (same size), and you always place the marker in the center of the table (or any other position that is considered your pivot), then yes you can do that. You will have to create the scene in Unity to fit the size of the table. For image tracking you will need to use Vuforia though instead of ARcore/ARkit

Comment: Ah gotcha, just tried out Vuforia with image tracking and it worked out pretty ok. We still want to go witch ARCore or ARKit tough, casue we're making this game for our course, but anyways. Here in this video they are doing exactly what we're trying to do https://youtu.be/y08xaz_XeoE?t=1m2s we just don't know how to implement it with code. Do you think there are guides or tutorials on this type of concept?

Comment: If that is what you are aiming for, then better use ARCore/ARkit or Vuforia's ground detection instead of image tracking. To save yourselves the complexity of  procedural generation, you can make your map beforehand in Unity, and then just spawn it on the surface you like (like the table). When you spawn it you could have the user resize it like in the video to fit the table. That is relatively easy to do. Just look at the ARCore example scene. With that you can put a 3d object in a tracked plane. Instead of that, you would put your whole map instead. Then the rest is it just your game logic

Comment: For resizing and rotating, just change the scale and rotation of the whole object based on touch input. I am sure you can find plenty of examples for that (not only for AR)

Answer (score 0):

`ARCore` (an augmented reality SDK) for `Android` is currently in Version 1.1.

The Detection of Flat surfaces like a table will be automatically detected from the ARCore SDK. If you're working with Unity, you can add a grass texture to the associated Prefab/GameObject for the detected planes.

Just download the ARCore SDK [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart) and run the sample app

If you're interestet on how to add the frass texture excactly, take a look at **[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLDczYMVF3o)**